# Probability of same genes or cards.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say there is a deck of 100 cards, you choose 6 cards of them. Another person also choose 6 in a new deck.

What is the probability of sharing one card?
What is the probability of sharing two cards?
...
What is the probability of sharing 6 cards?

I couldn't figure out the distribution.

there are 100C6 ways of choosing 6 cards but a second person also has those possibilities. How do I know if the card is the same?

If it was only a single card for both, then there are 100 ways of 100^2 = 1/100.
With two cards for both...

Maybe taking off artificially 6 cards from the second deck, then 100C6*94C6= number of ways without repeating a single card.
Then $(100C6*94C6)/(100C6)^2=(94C6)/(100C6)=0.68$ is the percentage of no cards repeated and 1-ans is the probability of 1|2|3|4|5|6?

If yes, how do I find individual cases?

Comment: "Other persons".... three?  four?  five?....?

Comment: Ignore the fact that the first person is choosing cards randomly.  Without loss of generality, let those cards drawn by the first person specifically be a named set of cards of your choosing.  You can work with a much smaller sample space now.  Compare this now to the question of having a bag with $6$ red balls and $94$ white balls, drawing six balls and asking for probabilities of various numbers of red balls drawn.  This is precisely the hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rephrase like this:

> There are $100$ cards and $6$ of them are marked. If someone picks $6$ of them randomly then what is the probability that among them there are exactly $k$ marked cards?

Think of it like this: you pick $6$ cards of the $100$ and mark them. Then the other person randomly picks $6$ of the cards.

The answer is gained by applying multihypergeometric distribution:$$\frac{\binom6k\binom{94}{6-k}}{\binom{100}6}$$

Comment: A proof or justification of the result would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

I am also learning probability recently, so here is my trial using hint from @JMoravitz, i.e. WLOG assume that $1$st person have already chosen cards $A,B,C,D,E,F$:

The probability that the second person shares only card $A$ with the first person:

$$P(\text{only card $A$ is shared})=\frac{{94\choose 89}}{{100\choose 6}}.$$

Then I guess to find out the probability that exactly $1$ card is shared (not necessarily card $A$), we need to multiply the above by ${6\choose 1}=6$.

So the answer for your first question I think: $6\times\frac{{94\choose 89}}{{100\choose 6}}$.

If this is true, the case when two people share exactly $2$ cards might calculated in similar way.

Comment: Card $A$ is one of the cards that was drawn by the first person

Comment: I think like @JMoravitz commented WLOG we can assume that 1st person already has chosen specific cards, lets say $A,B,C,D,E,F$. So here by $P(\text{only card $A$ is shared})$, I mean $P(\text{only card $A$ is shared} | \text{1st person have chosen cards $A,B,C,D,E,F$})$

Comment: Yes, but if card $A$ is in possession of the first player then there is sharing of card A if and only if card $A$ is picked by the second person. The probability on that is $\frac6{100}$. Oh, wait... you are saying "ony $A$". I need a second look on this now.

Comment: I see now that things are okay. Your $6\times\frac{\binom{94}{89}}{\binom{100}6}$ agrees with mine $\frac{\binom61\binom{94}5}{\binom{100}6}$. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I think if there was only 1 card chosen (not 6) by both person, then you are right. But in this case for example, the second person may have chosen 6 cards, and both $A$ and $B$ are among chosen ones, this is not inside $P(\text{only card $A$ is shared})$.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked "only".